# TFS Build: Pros & Cons of Single solution with 100 projects inside

Tags: tfsbuild

What do you think are the pros & cons of having a single big solution that TFS build will going to use?

Answer (score 2):

There should be no major cons as Visual Studio and TFS are designed to handle such scale.  Only your build time and your build drop size are affected by the number of projects that you build in TFS, so your TFS build machine specs should be verified to handle your tasks.

The main annoyance I've hit with that many projects in a solution is more on the development side. I hit constant conflicts with the .sln file if multiple people are adding/removing projects or modifying project settings.